# How to detect class change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have class "first" on my body , how I can detect its change to "second" and alert message

```
  if ($('body').hasClass('second'))
       alert("second");
    else
       alert("first");
```

Comment: Try approaching what you want to be done from a different perspective — You can't listen to class change events, but you can execute the function when you perform a class change on the body element.

Comment: You could fire a custom event when you actually change the class and you can capture this event whenever you need to. Or you can just do what you need when you actually change the class, depends on your need

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you need to create your own,something like:

```
$('body').addClass('my_class');

//add the 'classChanged', event
$('body').on('classChanged', some_callback);

function some_callback() {
    //do something
    alert("class changed");
}
//trigger for class change
$('body').trigger('classChanged');
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AezRE/)